# Open Subform in Access in New Window

Tags: forms, ms-access, filter, combobox, subform

I have a form in access ("F_Filter") where I indicate parameters to filter a datable. Form F_Filter also contains a subform which shows the filtered datatable results on the same screen. This subform with the filtered results is named "Child400." Its Source Object is "F_FilterResults".

I would like to be able to 1) open the subform in a new window so all I see are the filtered results and 2) export the results to Excel.

Normally I would be able to open a form in a new window by creating a button and creating an on click event with the following code

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "NameOfForm", acFormDS
```

However, this code does not work when I put in "Child400" as the NameOfForm. I think this is because Child400 is a subform and is not recognized by Access. 
I also tried `DoCmd.OpenForm "[F_Filter]![Child400]", acFormDS` to no avail. Note that I have also tried `DoCmd.OpenForm "F_FilterResults", acFormDS` which works fine but this table only contains the prefiltered results.

Answer (score 0):

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "F_FilterResults"
```

is the correct form to open. "Child400" is (I assume) the name of the subform control. That is not a form that you can open.

Then you need to apply the same filter as you did to the subform instance. The same method you use now for the subform can be used for the separate form.

If you have trouble with that, please add the existing filter code to your question.

**Edit**

There is no magic behind what records a form shows. It is controlled by a couple of properties. The easiest way is probably to simply take them over to the new form.

Something like:

```vb
Sub OpenResults()

    Dim fSub As Form, fNew As Form

    Set fSub = Me!Child400.Form

    DoCmd.OpenForm "F_FilterResults", acFormDS
    Set fNew = Forms!F_FilterResults

    fNew.RecordSource = fSub.RecordSource   ' if you change the RecordSource in your code
    fNew.Filter = fSub.Filter
    fNew.FilterOn = fSub.FilterOn
    fNew.OrderBy = fSub.OrderBy
    fNew.OrderByOn = fSub.OrderByOn

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried applying the same code to F_FilterResults but the results are not the same. (Note there are a few other events and parameters I am applying to the subform and F_FilterResults which I didn't mention in my post since they are somewhat complicated and extraneous to what I am trying to do now). I've spent a few hours trying to figure out where I went wrong with applying the same code to F_FilterResults but am not having luck. As such, I simply want to do a work around to display what I see in the Child400 subform.